# Java usando netbeans y acces como base de datos

Tags: java, base-de-datos, .htaccess

Estoy haciendo un proyecyo en java en el que tengo que utilizar una base de datos, pero tengo un problema que el programa descibre como "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbcUcanaccessDriver", no se como resolverlo, ayuda porfa. Adjunto la clase en la que tengo los métodos.

```
package martinez.adrian.contactosdbs;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
*
* @author ALUMNOS
*/
public class Metodos {
   static Logger login = Logger.getLogger ( Metodos.class.getName());
   public Connection obtenerConexion(){
       Connection conexion = null;
       try{
           Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc" + "UcanaccessDriver");
           String baseDatos = "jdbc:ucanaccess:///"+System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//ContactosDBS.accdb"; conexion = DriverManager.getConnection (baseDatos, "Minato", "Namikaze");
       }catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
           login.log(Level.SEVERE, null, cnfex);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR, DRIVER. \n" +cnfex);
       }catch(SQLException ex){
               Logger.getLogger(Metodos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR, CONEXION. \n" +ex);
       }                
       return conexion;
               
   }
```

Esa es mi clase donde estan los metodos,

Comment: Hola Adrian, es casi seguro que voy a decir una estupidez... no debería ir **Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc." + "UcanaccessDriver");** ?, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: No tienes que concatenar en `Class.forName`, sino poner un punto, prueba así: **`Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");`** Dicho eso, en versiones modernas, no hace falta usar `Class.forName`, basta con usar `DriverManager.getConnection()`. No sé que versión tengas de ese JDBC ¿? Otra cosa, para que funcione debes tener los `.jar` instalados en tu proyecto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Siempre en la diana! Podés prescindir del ``Class.forName`. O hacer lo que escribió @MarcePuente. Ejemplos en https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html#examples